# how to check that entered old password(in change password page) is correct or not?

Tags: ado.net

```
string str = "select password from registration";
                    if (str == textBox1.Text)
                    {

                        string str1 = "Update registration set password='" + textBox2.Text + "' where password='" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close()
                        MessageBox.Show("password changed");
                        this.Hide();
                     }
```

Comment: You should use params as your current way of building your SQL leaves your application open to injection attacks.

Comment: chris W:-sure i will but now wat to do with codes ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pull out the old password and then do the necessary checks. If the passwords are different, and the new password meets the necessary security criteria, then save it. If the DB update is successful, only then show the success method.

If you are storing your passwords as plain text, you might want to look at salting and hashing the passwords. On login, you salt and hash the users input and compare it against the hashed version in the DB.

Comment: actually i am little bit confused that how to fetch old password and match that with entered value

Comment: I presume the user is logged in to be able to change their password. You could use User.Identity.Name to get the logged in username, then use this in a query to fetch that users existing password (assuming it isn't hashed.)

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying in the first two lines of code?

```
string str = "select password from registration";
if (str == textBox1.Text)
```

as in your later code it seems like you are expecting the old password in textBox1. You should better store the result of the query in str rather than the query itself.

I am assuming that you are storing passwords as plain text and the registration table contains rows for user and password.

Registration

```
userid           Password
---------------------------
  1              abcdef
  2              xyzxyz
```

So you should do something like

```
int userId = 1; // userid of the user for which you want to change password
string str = "SELECT password from registration WHERE userid="+userid;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string oldPassword = string.Empty;
if (reader.HasRows)
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
     oldPassword = reader["password"].ToString() ;
   }
}

//now you can continue with other code with little modification is update query

 if (oldPassword == textBox1.Text)
 {

   string str1 = "Update registration set password='" + textBox2.Text + "' where password='" + textBox1.Text + "' and userid= " + userId;
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
   con.Open();
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close()
   MessageBox.Show("password changed");
   this.Hide();
 }
```